# Disabling IE8 accelerators for an entire site

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

(Yes, I know there is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499565/is-it-possible-to-disable-ie8-accelerators-on-my-website) on SO, but it's 8 months old -- since then IE8 RTM has come out -- and not very illuminating)

Is it possible to disable IE8's 'Accelerators' on my site?  When highlighting text, I have a small popup box that appears beside the cursor (similar to Office 2007) which is being obstructed by them.

I understand there's a method of disabling highlighting on specific elements of the site using jQuery, but this isn't ideal as I need to preserve the highlighting.

**Note**: I am *not* asking how to disable IE8 accelerators on my local copy of Internet Explorer.  Instead, I would like accelerators to not appear when anyone visits my site using IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this is deliberately not supported.

Please see http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/03/slowing-down-disabling-accelerators.aspx for discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the parent element as either contentEditable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837(VS.85).aspx) or as unselectable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537840(VS.85).aspx)

Either one should prevent the accelerator button from appearing.

Comment: What if I still want my text to be selectable but not allow the user to expand the page element the text is contained in?

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent highlighting on the section. Then wrap the selection that would have been highlighted in a span that has some CSS applied to it, mimicking the highlight. It might take a bit of work, but it would achieve your goals.

Comment: Interesting idea, but this will break my already existing code that relies on 'real' highlights.

Answer (score 0):

As someone says, wrap around selection with some span (ex. span class='selected' - to retrive it latter), and delete the selection with:

```
if (document.selection)//ie -> prevent showing the accelerator menu
{
 document.selection.empty();
}
```

Comment: What if the selection didn't begin and end within the same element?