# IE selection 'arrow'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

IE9 has this ridiculous blue arrow that's rendered any time the browser window has a selection:

[image]

This happens whether it's the user that makes the selection or programmatically through JavaScript (as in my case).  Is it possible to *not* have this blue arrow show up?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499565/is-it-possible-to-disable-ie8-accelerators-on-my-website and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574462/disabling-ie8-accelerators-for-an-entire-site

Comment: See Andrew Davey's reply at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499565/is-it-possible-to-disable-ie8-accelerators-on-my-website

Comment: oops I had no idea there were so many duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's IE9's "Accelerators". Disable them in the Tools -> Manage Add-Ons dialogue. MS thinks that no one will EVER highlight text unless they want to spam it to their FB wall.

Comment: It's strictly a user setting?  No way to temporarily disable it in a single page via JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe there's some funky `<meta>` tag you can specify (dig around on the IE9 developer pages on microsoft.com, maybe), but otherwise no. Since it's a browser plug-in, you can't do anything about disabling them remotely.